# How to allow access to .well-known directory

Tags: ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt

I had an SSL certificate through LetsEncrypt and it failed to regenerate and has now expired. When I try to generate a new certificate through LetsEncrypt or through zerossl.com I am getting errors.

It seems as though there is no access to the .well-known directory. How can I open up access to this hidden directory?

I am new to web development and my knowledge of code is limited, but I would appreciate any help at all!

Thanks!

Comment: What web server are you using?

Comment: Thanks for responding, Daniel. The web server is nginx

Comment: You might want to add the nginx tag, then, since that’s probably relevant. Additionally, what configuration are you trying for the `.well-known` path? What is the `root` directive? What OS and distribution are you using? I doubt you’re using server blocks since you say you’re new to web development, but that could also be relevant. In short, what have you tried, and can you give more relevant information?

Comment: I believe the OS is linux.

Comment: Here is the first portion of the response I received when I tried to obtain an SSL Certificate via sslforfree.com: Domain "brobenpeterson.com" challenge3 failed. Response from "https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/challenge/GCQNTskXTpzQpmI-wgCPA8oUDTHYOS6esiDpJOz_Df0/1471808439" was: { "type": "http-01", "status": "invalid", "error": { "type": "urn:acme:error:unauthorized", "detail": "Invalid response from http://brobenpeterson.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/AolGAydoUwNrQkwCJL7nCveIbv07bJdVDh4xjvBSTUE: \"\n\u003c!DOCTYPE html\u003e\n\n\u003chtml lang=\"en-US\" id=\"arve\"